# Search on an Internet Explorer App Object

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, powershell-ise

I have a `InternetExplorer.Application`

I am creating an automation
and one of the pages I opened, 
opened a dialog that looks like a new tab, but on the same process (I checked it by the **task manager** >> **process** tab that the same process just consumes more RAM) and I don't find the document if that dialog application.

Even in the `shell.application`
In the windows it isn't there.

I want help to find it

I thought to do some recursion on the `$ie` members to find a word that appears there and if it find a path post that path.

Thank you in advance

Comment: is this an iframe? can you physically see the window?

Comment: I can see the window but its not under $Ie.document.frames its looks like a new windows but somehow it prompt window

Comment: if you run this: `$ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')` you get anything?

Comment: Nope it not found anything.

already try requrcsion function but still nothing.

Comment: is there any chance my InternetExplorer need credentials for that web?

Comment: You can help me? Any other ideas please?

Comment: Can you give the url to trproduce the problem ?

Comment: i cant give it, it's inside company web.

Comment: Can you give any more info on this? I had some problems with IE and powershell before that magically vanished when I have updated Office...

Comment: Is it a prompt from javascript?  Are you able to inspect the element?

Comment: It's hard to tell what's the problem here.  Can you add some code to allow others to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the dialog box is a form within the same IE instance.  It would be a document element.

$ie.document.documentelement.all | foreach {$DE = $_ ; $DE | where {$_.innerhtml -match "My search arguement"}| foreach{$DE|select uniqueID}}

Once you identify the uniqueID then you can use $ie.Document.getElementById('ms__id14')

Answer (score 0):

It's a long shot but since it is in a company intranet, many times is can be a dialog telling you that you have SSL Certificate Error. It may be visible or not based on (wrongly?) enforced policies on your machine by the company. You might try to bypass it using this after navigating to the problematic URL:

```
    if ($ie.document.url -Match "invalidcert") {
        $bypass_link = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("a") | where-object {$_.id -eq "overridelink"}
        $bypass_link.click()
        while ($ie.ReadyState -ne 4) {
            start-sleep -m 100
        }
        "Done!"
    };
```